# Unable to Read an XML file into a data set when XML files containg data in French

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

I am trying to read an XML file into a data set using dataset.ReadXml(fileName, XmlReadMode.IgnoreSchema). XML contains data formatted in French eg 231,23 ie  '.' in US is replaced by ',' in French. I get an exception Input string was not in a correct format.Can any one help me ?

Comment: Can you provide the XML node.  Does the node specify the Type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your culture info to fr-FR

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR")
```

The parsing should not fail.

Answer (score 0):

While debugging take a look at the value of your dataset.Locale.NumberFormat.**NumberDecimalSeperator** property -- it is probably '.' by default and you'd want to change it to ',' before reading in the XML.